# magento 1.9 How to cancel an order in "Payment review"

Tags: magento-1.9, order-status

Sometimes an order gets stuck at "Payment review" status/state, and there is no way to cancel it through Magento. From magento I only can change them to "suspect fraud" status/state but I can't cancel them.

I can cancel the orders editing directly in the database the order in the tables sales_flat_order and sales_flat_order_grid.

Is there a way to do it directly with magento? Do I need to add by code a cancel button to the orders in this status/state?

Magento ver. 1.9.2.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I made an override of the core model Mage_Sales_Model_Order.

To override this file, copy app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php to app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php

In the file placed in local, find the `public function canCancel()` (over the line 545) and add to the beginning of the function:

```
if ($this->isPaymentReview()) {
    return true;
}
```

Now the cancel button is displayed on payment review status/state orders, and this way I'm able to cancel this orders.

Answer (score 0):

Below code worked for me.

```
 private function cancelPendingPayments() {

    $fromDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-2 hour'));
    $toDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime(now()));
    $orderCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_collection');

    $orderCollection->addFieldToFilter('status', 'pending_payment')
        ->addFieldToFilter('updated_at',  array( 'from' => $fromDate, 'to' => $toDate, 'date' => true ))
        ->getSelect()
        ->order('entity_id')
        ->limit(20);

    if( count( $orderCollection ) < 1 )  {
        return;
    }

    foreach( $orderCollection as $order ) {

        $difference = $this->getDifference($order);
        if( ( $difference >= 30 ) && ( $difference < 45 ) ) {

            $emailVariables = $this->pendingPaymentsVariables( $order );

            $this->prepareEmail( Mage::getStoreConfig('clearbasket_settings/email_template/pending_payment_notify'),
                                 $emailVariables, $emailVariables['orderdetails']['customername'], $emailVariables['orderdetails']['customeremail'] );
           $history = $order->addStatusHistoryComment('Notification email sent - Cron Jobs',false);
           $history->setIsCustomerNotified(false);
           $order->save();
        }

        if( $difference > 60 ) {

             if(!$order->canCancel()) {
                  Mage::log('Order cannot be canceled anymore.',null,"order.log");
              }
              else {
               $order->cancel();
    }
            $order->setData('state', "canceled");
            $order->setStatus("canceled");
            $order->setData('state', Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_CANCELED); 
            $order->setActionFlag(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::ACTION_FLAG_CANCEL, true);
            Mage::log('Order cancel after : '.$difference, null, "order.log");
            $history = $order->addStatusHistoryComment('Order marked as cancelled due to pending payment - Cron Jobs.', false);
            $history->setIsCustomerNotified(false);
            $order->save();
        }

    }

}
```

Please refer the link below for sending notification emails before cancelling and cron jobs.
https://www.pearlbells.co.uk/cancel-pending-payments-magento/